# Polynomial regression isn't taking my data because it's considering date to be strings

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

i made this program for a school project it works fine but my data should be in the form of dates
but every time i insert dates as variables it just promts me with an error saying **( can't float string "2022-05-16" )**

thanks in advance

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import datetime 

dataset = pd.read_csv('/content/Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values

dataset

"""from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)"""

"""from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test)"""

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X, y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the datetime column as a datetime-dtype rather than a string, you could use the `parse_dates` argument in [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv):

```py
dataset = pd.read_csv('/content/Position_Salaries.csv', parse_dates=...)
```

Or you could convert the datetime column to a datetime data type later using [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime):

```py
dataset[date_col] = pd.to_datetime(dataset[date_col])
```

Afterwards, you might want to extract date components using the [.dt accessor methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#dt-accessor).